# Check which characters exist in string (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, string

I'm attempting to create a function that detects which characters exist in a string. The function then returns a 26 character long string. This string will have 1 or a 0 in the character's position in the string depending on whether the character was found or not. So if a B and a Z are found the function will return

> 01000000000000000000000001

This what I have so far.

```
def convert(str)
    alpha = ("a".."z").to_a.join
    alpha.each_char do |i|
        num = 0
        (str.include? i) ? (alpha[num] = 1) : (alpha[num] = 0)
        num =+ 1
    end
    print ans
end
convert("a 345 % b ^    xxz")
```

However, I keep getting an error on the 5th line:

> No implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)

Not sure how to get around this. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a number into a string. Replace the `1` and `0` on that line with `"1"` and `"0"`.

Also, I think you mean `num += 1` instead of `num = +1`!

Comment: My goodness... I'm an idiot. Too much coding for one day apparently. ;) thanks!

Comment: @codedude you are not an idiot. You are a human who makes mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the error by using [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
def convert(str)
  ('a'..'z').map { |c| str.include?(c) ? 1 : 0 }.join
end

convert("a 345 % b ^    xxz")
#=> "11000000000000000000000101"
```